# Find the value of $A$ if $\sin(A+B)=1$ and $\sin(A-B)=\dfrac{1}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin(A+B)=1$ and $\sin(A-B)=\dfrac{1}{2}$, find all the possible values for $A$?

Comment: See http://www.math-only-math.com/sin-theta-equals-sin-alpha.html

Comment: Also see http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Trig/TrigGenSol.htm and http://www.math-only-math.com/trigonometric-equation-formula.html.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin(A+B)=1$ implies $A+B = \frac{\pi}{2}+2m\pi$ with $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.
$\sin(A-B)=\frac{1}{2}$ implies $A-B\in\left\{\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}\right\}+2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. It follows that
$$ A = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6}+2m\pi+2n\pi\right)=\frac{\pi}{3}+k\pi,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z} $$
or
$$ A = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{5\pi}{6}+2m\pi+2n\pi\right)=\frac{2\pi}{3}+k\pi,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z} $$
so $A\in\frac{\pi}{3}\mathbb{Z}\setminus\pi\mathbb{Z}$.